# Why is my code not throwing the EntityExistsException

Tags: java, mysql, jakarta-ee, exception, jpa

I'm currently studying Java EE 7, and was trying to figure out when the `EntityExistsException` would be thrown. I currently have a very simple Message class with basic attributes. To my understanding, when a entity with same primary key that is to be persisted already exists in the database, the `EntityExistsException` should be thrown. I wasn't too sure whether it would matter if the said entity was detached or not, so made a quick test to see when it would occur. However both the test cases pass for some reason, without showing me the error.

```
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.EntityTransaction;
import javax.persistence.Persistence;
import org.iys.jpa.mysql.example.Message;
import org.junit.After;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertFalse;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertTrue;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertTrue;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;

public class MessageIT {

    private static EntityManagerFactory emf ; 
    private EntityManager em;
    private EntityTransaction tx;

    public MessageIT() {
    }

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
       emf= Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("JPAMYSQLExampleU");
        em = emf.createEntityManager();
        tx = em.getTransaction();
        Message m1= new Message("Hello");       
        tx.begin();
        em.persist(m1);        
        tx.commit();
        System.out.println("Setting up the test");
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() {
        if (em != null) {
            em.close();
        }
    }

    //either one of the test should fail

    @Test
    public void shouldFail1(){
        Message msg = em.find(Message.class, 1L);
        Message copied= msg;    
        copied.setMessage("changed");
        assertTrue(em.contains(msg));
        em.clear();
        assertFalse(em.contains(msg));
        assertFalse(em.contains(copied));  //both entities are currently detached
        tx.begin();
       em.persist(copied);

        tx.commit();

    }
    @Test
    public void shouldFail2(){
        Message msg = em.find(Message.class, 1L);
        assertTrue(em.contains(msg));
        tx.begin();
        em.persist(msg);
        tx.commit();
    }
}
```

If I'm misunderstanding the conditions for the error to occur, how would you change the code so the aforementioned error is thrown.

Comment: p.s. The test results 3 different rows in db (1, Hello), (2, changed), (3, Hello)

Comment: It's 4:50 am here, and I've been wrestling over this for last 5 hours going through books and similar questions on stackoverflow. I am going to bed for now. I will appreciate any inputs regarding the matter. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably are using `@GeneratedValue` for your Id (would be good if you could provide your entity implementation in the question). In that case provider with persist might just generate new id before persisting entity. (this is why shouldFail1 doesn't fail).

And in case of shouldFail2 specification states:

> If X is a preexisting managed entity, it is ignored by the persist
>   operation.

and since your `msg` is managed in that test, persist is simply ignored.

You better switch to provided Id instead of generated to test `EntityExistsException` case.

Comment: Thank you very much. As you suggested Id indeed was GeneratedValue.